# How to invoking Oracle CCI from a Command Line

Tags: oracle, cci

I successfully installed the Oracle Code Compliance Inspector (CCI) extension for JDeveloper by following the instructions. Afterwards I was able to run CCI in JDeveloper. But I'm not able to invoke Oracle CCI from a Command Line.

I can't find the script ("`checkCompliance.sh`") mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e17366/chapter20.htm#A1145803). It's not part of the [zip file](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jdeveloper/11.1.1.7.0/extensions/complianceInspector-jdev-extension.zip) I downloaded from oracle.com.

I tried to run the `compliance.policy.engine.jar` file directly but this fails with an error message:

```
java -jar /oracle/jdevhome/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.fp.compliance.inspector/lib/compliance.policy.engine.jar -inputDir /AIA/demo -outputDir /ComplianceOut
```

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
>   /oracle/jdevhome/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.fp.compliance.inspector/lib/compliance.policy.engine.jar

Any suggestions on how to invoke CCI from a command line or where I can find the script mentioned in the documentation?

Regarding the error message I read that this can be fixed by adding a manifest file to the jar archive which defines the Main-Class - but which one is the Main-Class of this jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's solved.

As mentioned in [this part of the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e15754/codecomplianceinsp.htm#A1117113), the CCI command line tools are distributed with Oracle Enterprise Repository (OER).

```
The CCI command line tools are distributed with OER within the <OER Oracle Home>/tools/solutions/<version>-ComplianceInspector.zip.
```

What confused me: The OER-Download only contained a single `.jar` file. It took me some time to realise that the `.jar` file is a installer.

> java -jar OER111170_generic.jar [-log=full_path_to_log_file]

See [installation documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/doc.1111/e15745/install.htm) for detailed instructions.

#### checkCompliance.sh

After successfully installing OER, I found the `<version>-ComplianceInspector.zip` in `<OER Home>/repository111/core/tools/solutions/`.

The `<version>-ComplianceInspector.zip` actually contained the `checkCompliance.sh` file.